# Excel VLOOKUP or INDEX MATCH

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Lets say I have 3 columns of data

```
AMOUNT(A)  AMOUNT(B)     INVOICE(C)
55          49           4541
47          47           1515
42          47           4478
86          12           9993
12          100          1224
5           44           1452
            100          4287
            99           4444
```

What I need to check to see if the value in column A matches a value in column B. If there is a match, it will return the value from column C in column D. Now this is easy with a VLOOKUP however I am dealing with 700+ lines and there are multiple amounts that match. INDEX(MATCH) could work but it only returns one value. Is this a VB only problem?

I.E Value 47 exists in column B twice so therefore column D would return both invoice numbers (1515 - 4478)

Comment: To my experience, yes this requires VBA code.  Index and Vlookup both only return the first result they encounter.

Comment: Do you prefer formulas or VBA?? If your first choice is to do this solely with formulas, I really don't think it's going to work out. You can get close with Excel array formulas but I don't know any non-VBA way around the inability of CONCATENATE to take a range/array and its lacking of a delimiter. The array method will work with a small UDF for concatenation. Or you could write a UDF for the whole thing.

Comment: Yes an array formula would do but not returning on a single cell on D column alone as what @MarkBalhoff pointed out.

Comment: @Treevar, Have a look below for the non-VBA based solution

Comment: I'm not against using VBA but I wanted to have a solution that someone without VBA experience could edit. HNK your solution is great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VBA, the problem would be trivial as you have already correctly described the logic with the problem statement itself.

Using Excel functionality only, without VBA is the interesting problem. You need to do the following steps to achieve an output that looks like this...

[image]

The steps are as follows:

1. **Pivot Table:** Make a pivot-table from the Columns `(B)` and `(C)` with Rows Fields as `(B)` and `(C)` and the minimum of `AMOUNT(B)` as the Value field. (See Figure below)
2. **Helper Columns:** Make a column on the side of the pivot table, say `(Q)` which is simply equal to everything in column `(P)`
3. **Contd ... :** In column `(R)` (which unfortunately happens to be in the sheet's column Q, sorry for the confusion there), as shown, for cell `Q20` for e.g. put in the formula

   `=IF(P21=P20,Q21&","&M20,M20)`
4. That will result in the creation of something like the table below:

Table:

```
(P) (Q)

12  9993
44  1452
47  4478,1515
47  4478
49  4541
99  4444
100 4287,1224
100 4287
```

Now the hard work is done. All you need to do is to lookup using `VLOOKUP` key-value pairs from this helper table `(P)(Q)`
- It will be very fast because the pivot table always keeps it sorted and hence an exact `LOOKUP` is not necessary.
- Screenshots are shown below for the Pivot table as well as for the final `VLOOKUP` formula

**Pivot Table and Helper Table:**

[image]

**Final Formula:**

[image]

Comment: I must be missing something. Under my reading of the OP's question, he wants a column that logically goes next to column A and is a list of all invoices for that amount. You seem to assume A) that column A is part of same table as column B/C and B) that the OP's desire is to see all invoices with a matching amount in the current flat table format. Neither assumption fits into my reading of the question. How will your question ever "return both invoice numbers" if that number is only in Column A once?

Comment: @MarkBalhoff, The method above should work without any VBA based macros/formulae. Do have a look.

Comment: Much better. A solid non-VBA answer. Your formula in R and your text act like there is data in column P but your image shows that empty. After a slight tweak there it works on my end. Personally, I avoid using pivot tables as intermediate processing tools but if formulas are preferred then any other option will be messier. If the OP's data is not stagnant though the OP may have to ensure the pivot table refreshes and/or expand the data source range. Oh and on the strange off chance the OP cares about any invoice sort order on the first table, this could be problematic.

Comment: Yes, I would find VBA a better option. Also yes, the screenshots were taken before I shifted some columns, but it's quite clear, I hope. Finally, I agree - pivot tables are meant to pivot data and not to do fancy sorting, but in this case if for security reasons (only .xlsx allowed, etc.) if someone just has to use non-VBA solutions, this is neat, easily maintainable, etc. Regd. Sort Order, that can be handled via pivot table by sorting column (C) differently - some sorting hierarchy can be achieved.

Comment: The data is not dynamic in this instance. VBA would be a better option I agree, but I wanted to try to have this as a non-vba solution so novice users could use a similar system should this be required in the future. Thanks hnk!

Answer (score 1):

so I'm using the Countif to see if there are dups based on column A. 
In the D column type, `=IF(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$9,B2)>0,C2,"")`

[image]